# How can you modify an image using tkinter scales?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, tkinter

I'm fairly new to Python and OpenCV, so I apologize if anything I say/ask may sound unintelligent or uninformed.  We have learned things in my Digital Image Processing class in a very specific way, so while my code below works, I would like to vastly improve its speed, but mostly its UI.  The main purpose of the code is to create a binary matte of a greenscreen image, which it then applies to the image to separate the foreground from the background.  As for the functions:

***keyer*** creates a thresholded matte of the input image, dependent on which type of matte is desired (colorDifference or chromaKey).

***thresholdAdjust*** allows the user to manipulate threshold sliders through the Open CV UI.  It also live updates the image (when the Enter key is pressed) to reflect how the raw matte changes according to the chosen threshold values.  Since I was completely new to these features, all of the examples that I saw used a function like ***tracker***.  I'm not sure if it's necessary though.

Lastly, ***keyMultiplier*** applies the matte produced in ***thresholdAdjust*** to the input image and displays the separated foreground.

(It is not necessary to read through all of the ***keyer*** code since it works properly, yet a little slowly.  I included all of it just in case.)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def keyer(image, matteType, threshold1, threshold2, maxCount=255):

    numberRows = image.shape[0]
    numberColumns = image.shape[1]

    if image.ndim > 2:
        numberBands = image.shape[2]
    else:
        numberBands == 1

    if numberBands != 3:
        raise RuntimeError('Input image must be an RGB image.')

    dataType = image.dtype

    matte = np.zeros((numberRows, numberColumns, 1))
    imageNorm = image / float(maxCount)

    if matteType == 'colorDifference':
        blue, green, red = cv2.split(imageNorm)

        for row in range(numberRows):
            for column in range(numberColumns):        
                pixel = green[row, column] - max(red[row, column], blue[row, column])

                matte[row, column] = pixel

    elif matteType == 'chromaKey':
        imageYCbCr = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
        imageYCbCrNorm = imageYCbCr / float(maxCount)
        Y, Cr, Cb = cv2.split(imageYCbCrNorm)
        CbScreen =  Cb[0, 0]
        CrScreen = Cr[0, 0]

        for row in range(numberRows):
            for column in range(numberColumns):
                pixel = float(np.sqrt(((CbScreen - Cb[row, column])**2) + \
                                      ((CrScreen - Cr[row, column])**2)))

                matte[row, column] = pixel

    else:
        raise RuntimeError('Please enter a valid "matteType".')

    matte = np.clip(matte, 0.0, 1.0)

    if matteType == 'colorDifference':
        matte = 1.0 - matte

    for row in range(numberRows):
        for column in range(numberColumns):

            if matte[row, column] < threshold1:
                matte[row, column] = 0
            elif matte[row, column] > threshold2:
                matte[row, column] = 1
            else:
                matte[row, column] = ((matte[row, column] - threshold1) / \
                                      (threshold2 - threshold1))

    return (matte * float(maxCount)).astype(dataType)

def tracker(*arg):
    pass

def thresholdAdjust(image, matteType, maxCount):
    numberRows = image.shape[0]
    numberColumns = image.shape[1]

    if matteType == 'colorDifference':
        matteName = '(Color Difference)'
    else:
        matteName = '(Chroma Key)'

    windowName = 'Adjust Matte Parameters ' + matteName        
    threshold1TrackbarName = 'Clip Black'
    threshold2TrackbarName = 'Clip White'

    cv2.namedWindow(windowName)
    cv2.createTrackbar(threshold1TrackbarName, windowName, 0, maxCount, tracker)
    cv2.createTrackbar(threshold2TrackbarName, windowName, 0, maxCount, tracker)

    cv2.setTrackbarPos(threshold2TrackbarName, windowName, maxCount)

    while True:
        threshold1 = (cv2.getTrackbarPos(threshold1TrackbarName, windowName) / \
                      float(maxCount))
        threshold2 = (cv2.getTrackbarPos(threshold2TrackbarName, windowName) / \
                      float(maxCount))

        window = keyer(image, matteType, threshold1, threshold2, maxCount)
        cv2.imshow(windowName, window)

        k = cv2.waitKey(0)
        if k == 27:
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    return threshold1, threshold2

def keyMultiplier(image, matteType, maxCount):
    dataType = image.dtype

    threshold1, threshold2 = thresholdAdjust(image, matteType, maxCount)
    matte = keyer(image, matteType, threshold1, threshold2, maxCount)

    return ((cv2.GaussianBlur((matte / float(maxCount)), (3, 3), 0)[..., np.newaxis]) * \
            image).astype(dataType)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import cv2

    filename = 'C:/Users/Matt/Documents/circle_test.tif'

    image = cv2.imread(filename)


    difference = keyMultiplier(image, matteType='colorDifference', maxCount=255) # 163, 215
    chroma = keyMultiplier(image, matteType='chromaKey', maxCount=255) # 25, 50

    cv2.imshow('Original Image', image)
    cv2.imshow('Color Difference', difference)
    cv2.imshow('Chroma Key', chroma)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What I would like to do with this code is use it with a Tkinter UI since it is nicer and has more options than OpenCV's.  I've been looking over a ton of threads and I haven't found anything that helps me understand my specific problem.  I did find one answer on this Stack Overflow that provided the following code, which I reformatted to reflect my code's purpose.  It prints the values of the sliders each time the slider control is released.

```
from Tkinter import *

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title('Adjust Matte Parameters')

        self.clipBlack = Scale(self.root, from_=0, to=255, orient=HORIZONTAL, \
                               label='Clip Black', length=500)
        self.clipBlack.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.updateValue)
        self.clipBlack.pack(anchor=CENTER)

        self.clipWhite = Scale(self.root, from_=0, to=255, orient=HORIZONTAL, \
                               label='Clip White', length=500)
        self.clipWhite.set(255)
        self.clipWhite.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.updateValue)
        self.clipWhite.pack(anchor=CENTER)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def updateValue(self, event):
        print 'Clip Black = ' + str(self.clipBlack.get())
        print 'Clip White = ' + str(self.clipWhite.get())

app = App()
```

However, this raises a few more issues.  While I really like that it immediately retrieves the slider positions, all this does is print them.  I would like to those values to instead be inserted into the ***keyer*** function as I implemented in ***thresholdAdjust***.  A such, I would like to update the image, but I have had no luck showing an image using OpenCV while a Tkinter window is open since the "root.mainloop()" line appears to not allow it.  I have found some help regarding display a Tkinter and OpenCV window at the same time, as well as displaying an image using Tkinter, but those options are irrelevant until I can update the matte with the new threshold values.

I also don't really understand how to handle classes and functions within them.  I am only used to running code by creating a test harness as shown below

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

in the first block of code, so I wouldn't know how to, say, determine the image and matteType I want to use without hardcoding it.

If anyone could help me out, that would be much appreciated!  I know it's a lot, and I'd be happy to clear up any confusion.  Once I know how to accomplish this with a slider, I should be able to apply it to radio buttons as well.  Again, I would like to:

- Update my ***keyer*** function using the threshold sliders
- Live update the matte, either using OpenCV or Tkinter, whichever is easier
- Understand how to, if applicable, change the input image and other variables in a class

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've been pouring over this for hours and I think I finally found a solution (you will need a `.png` file name `picture.png` in the same directory in order to run the below):

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.frame1 = Frame(self)
        self.frame2 = Frame(self)
        self.original = Image.open('picture.png')
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.original)
        self.display = Canvas(self.frame1)
        self.xscale = Scale(self.frame2, from_=1, to=1000, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=self.resize)
        self.yscale = Scale(self.frame2, from_=1, to=1000, orient=VERTICAL, command=self.resize)
        self.display.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.xscale.pack()
        self.yscale.pack()
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.frame1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.frame2.pack()
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)

    def resize(self, *args):
        size = (self.xscale.get(), self.yscale.get())
        resized = self.original.resize(size,Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
        self.display.delete("IMG")
        self.display.create_image(self.display.winfo_width()/2, self.display.winfo_height()/2, anchor=CENTER, image=self.image, tags="IMG")

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
app.mainloop()
```

So what this does is create a `canvas` and two `scale`s, whenever one of the `scale`s is changed it will call the `def` `resize` which clears the items with tag `IMG` from the canvas and then draw a new image with `width` equal to the value of `xscale` and height equal to `yscale` with a tag of `IMG`. The creates the illusion of real time size updates as you drag the slider along the `scale`s.

I could not, however, figure out a way to limit the `scale`s upper values to the width of the `canvas` in pixels to prevent the user from expanding the image outside of the bounds of the `canvas`.

This could similarly be applied to allow you to live update whatever attributes of the image you needed to update with a slider value.

Answer (score 0):

here is my work sample, FYI.

```
def scale_value(value):
    global  imgtk, label
    thresh = scale_thresh.get()
    (thresh_out, img_bin) = cv2.threshold(img, thresh, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    img_RGB = cv2pil(img_bin) #BGR to RGB

    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img_RGB)
    label = tk.Label(win,image=imgtk).place(x = 10,y = 70, width = 320, height = 240)

def cv2Scale():
    global label, scale_thresh, win, imgtk, img

    win=tk.Tk()                                                      
    win.title("tkinter GUI test")*emphasized text*
    win.geometry("600x400")

    img = cv2.imread("test.png")
    height, width = img.shape[:2]
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #scale
    scale_thresh = tk.Scale(win, label="Threshold", from_=0, to=255, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=scale_value) 
    scale_thresh.set(60) #default value
    scale_thresh.place(x = 10, y = 10, width = 260, height = 70)

    #cv2 numpy to PIL. OK
    img_RGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA) # BGR to RGB
    img_RGB = Image.fromarray(img_RGB) #cv2(numpy.ndarray) to TK(PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile)

    #img show on lable first. ok
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img_RGB)
    label = tk.Label(win,image = imgtk).place(x = 10,y = 70, width = 320, height = 240)

    win.mainloop()
```